# Finding the cardinality of $\{ X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) : |X| \leqslant 1 \}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that $|A| = m$, my task is to find the cardinality of the set $Q = \{ X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) : |X| \leqslant 1 \}$. Since this is an even-numbered exercise in the text I'm working through, it hasn't got a solution. What I think is that if we let $ A = \{ x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_m \}, $ then we're looking for the set $$ Q = \{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \}, \{\{x_1\}\}, \{\{x_2\}\}, \dots, \{\{x_m\}\}, \{\{x_1, x_2\}\}, \{\{x_1, x_3\}\}, \dots, \{\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\}, \{\{x_1,x_2,x_4\}\}, \dots \} $$ According to this, $|Q| = |\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{m}$. Am I on the right lines?

Comment: First solve the easier problem of finding the size of $\{X\subseteq B\colon |X|\le 1\}$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo - The size of that set would be the cardinality of $B$, would it not?

Comment: No, it isn't. $\le$ does not mean $=$.

Comment: Another hint: The list of elements of $Q$ in your question is missing $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo In that case, then $|\{ X \subseteq B : |X| \leqslant 1 \}| \leq |B|$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, I've added it in.

Comment: After adding in $\{\varnothing\}$ to $Q$, you should adjust $|Q|$ accordingly on the next line of the question.  (But now Patrick Da Silva has given an answer that covers this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $Q$ is a weird way of saying 'The set of subsets of $A$ which contain at most one element', i.e. $Q$ is the set of ''subsets with at most one element, and this element is a subset of $A$''. So we have a canonical bijection between $Q$ and $\mathcal P(A) \cup \{*\}$ (where $*$ is just meant to be some extra element I add in there), and the bijection is given as follows : if $B \subseteq A$, then $B \mapsto \{ B \}$, and $* \mapsto \varnothing$ (the empty set is not the same thing as the set containing $\varnothing \subseteq A$).

For instance, if $A = \{x,y\}$, 
$$
Q = \{ \quad \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \}, \{ \{ x \} \}, \{ \{ y \} \}, \{ \{x,y\} \} \quad \}
$$
would be the full list, and the bijection above would be as follows : 
$$
\varnothing \mapsto \{\varnothing\} \\
\{x\} \mapsto \{\{x\}\} \\
\{y\} \mapsto \{ \{ y \} \} \\
\{x,y \} \mapsto \{\{x,y\}\} \\
* \mapsto \varnothing.
$$

From this explanation, you should derive $|Q| = 2^{|A|} + 1$.

Hope that helps,